# OpenMP code C++ is slower thatn c++

Tags: c++, openmp

i have the following part of code, i run it on sample of N=3000, the c++ sequential code is faster by 3 seconds which is not good at all.

this code is filling the array jsd[N] with calculated values and i want to locate the maximum value and its location. 
so 
1- is this openmp conversion correct, and is there any better suggstion to make it more profissional
2- why it is slower that the equavilant c++ code, also the more threads i create the more it get slow.

thanks in advance

```
double maxval = 0;
int pos = -1;
double jsd[N];
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) 
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  double Hl = obj.function1(sequenceVctr, i, LEFT);
  double Hr = obj.function1(sequenceVctr, i, RIGHT);
  jsd[i] = obj.function2(H, i + 1, N, Hl, Hr);   

  if (jsd[i] >= maxval) {
      #pragma omp critical 
      {
        maxval = jsd[i];
         pos = i;
      }
  }
}  // for
```

update:

here is the new code but still  slow and get slower in more threads.
i update the code as following. but still get slower for more threads

```
double maxval = 0;
int pos = -1;
double jsd[N];
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(50)
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  double Hl = obj.function1(sequenceVctr, i, LEFT);
  double Hr = obj.function1(sequenceVctr, i, RIGHT);
  jsd[i]= obj.function2(H, i + 1, N, Hl, Hr);

}  // for
#pragma omp master
{
    vector<double> jsd2 (jsd,jsd+N);
    vector<double>::iterator jsditer;
  jsditer = std::max_element(jsd2.begin(), jsd2.end());
  maxval=*jsditer;
  pos=std::distance(jsd2.begin(),jsditer) ;
 // cout<<"pos"<<pos<<endl;
} 
#pragma omp barrier
```

Comment: how do you measure the time?

Comment: Not an answer-  but I think that your if (jsd[i] >= maxval) belongs in the critical section

Comment: Can you take a moment to make your post a little more presentable?

Comment: Do you really think 50 threads work better than 4?

Answer (score 3):

The first optimization I would suggest is to first compute all jsd values in the loop, then find the maximum element via `std::max_element()`.
This way you are not forcing the threads to synchronise.

The second thing I would do is move over to Intel TBB instead of OpenMP and use `parallel_reduce()`.

But the biggest question is, how complex are the objective functions you are evaluating.

Comment: Your first paragraph is exactly what I would suggest as well. Synchronization can severely limit the benefits of multi-threading

Comment: the function1 is the thing that slows the application coz it has a hashmap.. but function2 is simiple calculation

Comment: also. std::max_element() only works for vecors and jsd is an array and when i want to insert (push_back) into vector in a parallel code it produces conflict.

Comment: You should read more about the STL and how these things work. You can perform any of these iterator-based functions on arrays. The iterator is a pointer into the array in this case. You can also savely access a  `std::vector`'s elements in parallel if you first create the vector with the correct size and then access like the array. Or use C++11's `std::array()`.

Comment: i update the code as following. but still get slower for more threads

Comment: You should really try `double *best = std::max_element(jsd, jsd + N); pos = best - jsd; maxval = *best;` although it won't solve your performance problem ;)